# What does "Gate W" mean for a track assignment of an Amtrak train at Penn Station?

Tags: new-york-city, train-stations, amtrak

I know of a number of different entrances to the Track 5-6 platform from various parts of Penn Station. [This site](https://jasongibbs.com/pennstation/) contains a set of nice maps detailing the station layout, indicating the entrances to each platform from the concourses.

An Amtrak train's track assignment looks like this:

[image: Amtrak Gate/Track assignment showing "Gate: W Track: 6"]

I haven't been able to find any reference for what the Gate assignment refers to. I presume that it means only one of the entrances to the track 5-6 platform are open, but I haven't been able to figure out which "Gate" is "W". (Presumably "West", but relative to what, given that there are at least three entrance locations to this platform on the Amtrak side of the station?)

Comment: I suggest West Concourse. Why did they name it is way I have no clue

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest it means "West", as well.  My assumption is that this is a result of the recently-opened Moynihan concourse geographically "West" of the original Penn Station building.  This is a new concourse (as of January 2021) to get down to track level in addition to the original concourse of the original Penn Station structure.  I believe the original concourse is still there, but probably not used for much (though I don't know for sure, as I've only been there on a through train and never got off to see the inside of the station itself).

The Moynihan Train Hall was originally the Farley post office, and recently went through a huge (both effort and cost) remodeling effort to create a much less "rat maze" way of dealing with railroad passengers going through the dank basement remnants of the original glorious Penn Station.

Here is the Moynihan Train Hall website for further reference:  https://www.moynihantrainhall.nyc/